# Jquery/.NET Core JSON returned cannot be parsed

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-core

This is what I send to my controller:

> "[{\"PropertyName\":\"fewfewf\",\"Key\":\"ewgwewe\",\"PrimaryValue\":\"\",\"SecondaryValue\":\"\",\"TertiaryValue\":\"\",\"MinimumValue\":\"\",\"MaximumValue\":\"\"},{\"PropertyName\":\"rwhjyjut\",\"Key\":\"jtyjyt\",\"PrimaryValue\":\"\",\"SecondaryValue\":\"\",\"TertiaryValue\":\"\",\"MinimumValue\":\"\",\"MaximumValue\":\"\"}]"

This is what I receive back from the server after I parse and serialize it again.

[image]
I am very confused as I haven't changed anything. When I try to parse it Jquery side, I get this error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2

This is the jquery code

```
if ("@Model.FormPropertiesList".length !== 0) {
    console.log($.parseJSON("@Model.FormPropertiesList"));
}
```

Am i Missing something?

EDIT: This is my serverside code

```
var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<NewFormPropertyViewModel>>(Input.FormPropertiesList);
Input.FormPropertiesList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
return View("Create", Input);
```

This is how i convert the string to JSON

```
$("#@Html.IdFor(m => m.FormPropertiesList)").val(JSON.stringify(dataSet));
```

Comment: The string that you try to parse client side looks like it's encoded for some reason

Comment: jQuery's `parseJSON` function has been deprecated, instead use the native `JSON.parse()` method.  http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/

Comment: Same issue with JSON..parse(). I get the same error

Comment: Because of the encoding....

Comment: We need to see the JS code which is creating that encoded JSON and how you send it to the controller, as that's the source of the problem

Comment: Where did you grab the data from your first snippet from?  Did you grab it from the network console from the request itself?  Because stringify shouldn't be escaping the json with `\\` like that

Comment: The first snippet came from the serverside. Once the form has been submitted.

Comment: Ok, so there's something weird there.  Valid json will not have the " escaped like that.  Can you grab it from the request on the client and show us what that looks like?

Comment: [{"PropertyName":"wegewg","Key":"ewgew","PrimaryValue":"","SecondaryValue":"","TertiaryValue":"","MinimumValue":"","MaximumValue":""},{"PropertyName":"tkytk","Key":"tykytk","PrimaryValue":"","SecondaryValue":"","TertiaryValue":"","MinimumValue":"","MaximumValue":""}] - Here is what I got

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string is being HTML encoded. You can use [`@HTML.Raw`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper.raw?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2) to tell razor to put the `string` as is. One of the reasons strings get encoded is for security purposes. Say you are trying to display some data you just fetched from a database and that data has some "malicious" JavaScript, while this code will be harmless to the database, it will affect the client once the view is rendered. You can try:

```
if ("@Model.FormPropertiesList".length !== 0) {
    console.log(JSON.parse("@HTML.Raw(Model.FormPropertiesList)"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First replace your "&quot"

```js
var serverrep= "[{&quot;PropertyName&quot;:&quot;fewfewf&quot;,&quot;Key&quot;:&quot;ewgwewe&quot;,&quot;PrimaryValue&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;SecondaryValue&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;TertiaryValue&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;MinimumValue&quot;:&quot;&quot;,&quot;MaximumValue&quot;:&quot;&quot;}]"


var serverRepWithoutQuots=serverrep.replace(/&quot;/g, '"');
console.log(serverRepWithoutQuots)
console.log(JSON.parse(serverRepWithoutQuots))
```

Comment: This is very strange though. What am I doing wrong that I need to replace it?

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue like this when passing JSON to my template then to my js file in Django. When you do this in Django you pass something from the view in the context, then when you're in the Django template you would do something like

```
var someName = {{ fromView }};
```

and I had it wrapped in doubles quotes

```
var someName = "{{ fromView }}";
```

so it was escaping the double quotes in the JSON that was parsed. I spent like 2 hours trying to figure out what was up and I literally had to just change the double quotes to single quotes because it was reading it as a string with double quotes that had another string(json string) with double quotes in it

```
var someName = '{{ fromView }}';
```

point being I would check the JSON to make sure you're not passing it the wrong way and it's being encoded improperly / adding extra quotes somewhere

Comment: Hello! Thanks for giving this solution. I'm using .net core and I tried replacing it with single quotes as well. However I'm getting the same issue. It seems like the double quotes come from the server.

Comment: I suppose another option may be that what you're getting from the server is already JSON serialized and then you're serializing again so it's being encoded. I believe this can happen with some things such as webapi. I haven't written any .net in a while so I'm not really sure but I suppose it's worth a try. Try not manually serializing it and see if maybe the server is just returning it serialized to begin with?